# Use of position property in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in CSS and need help with a suggestion.

I'm working on a project, in which I managed to position `container_main` right next to `container_menu` giving the remaining dimension of the screen, giving it relative position and floating it to the right. `container_menu` has a dimension and a fixed position specified.

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

/*Contenedor de la barra de navegacion: Columna*/
.container_menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 18rem;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  position: fixed;
  background-color: gray;
}

/*Barra de navelación: Elemento <ul>*/
.container_menu .menu {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.container_menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container_menu .menu li a{
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  background-color: gray;
}

.container_menu .menu li a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.container_main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 66.31rem;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

p {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 30rem;
  height: 20rem;
  border: .7rem solid white;;
  padding: 5rem;
  margin: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300i,400" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>MDN - Mockup</title>
</head>
<body class="wrapper">
  <nav class="container_menu">

    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Teaching Activities</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Web Literacy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Leadership Opportunities</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Comunity</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <main class="container_main">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
      ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
      voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
      non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
       ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
       laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
       voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
       non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
       ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
       laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
       voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
       non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  </main>

  <<footer></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to know if the characteristics I gave the containers are ideal, or if there is a better way to get the same result using other properties.

Thank you.

Comment: Questions on how to improve code that already works should go on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) SE

Comment: Looks good but making it responsive (if u have the task to do it) won't be quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code and requirements I don't see a problem the way you are implementing so my answer is that your implementation is all good and doesn't need any change. I used the same method in few of my own sites.